# Adding instances from excel into ontology created in protege using graphDB

Tags: graphdb

I have been using GraphDB to load instances from excel sheet to the created ontology in protege.

I was able to upload my RDF (or Ontology file) in GraphDB repository, but I don't know how to load instances. When I loaded my ontology file, I was not able see any Graph hierarchy or class relationship diagram.

It shows, **"The currently selected repository contains no dependencies data. Please, reload the diagram if you have imported data recently".**

What does this mean? How to load instances into GraphDB?

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you must upload in "Import / Tabular (Ontorefine)" and refine your excel sheet. Open sparql and run. Ready: now save as rdf-xml. Import the rdf-xml created and ready.

Answer (score 0):

As described above, you can export your data to RDF (rdf-xml, turtle, etc) from OntoRefine. You should use a CONSTRUCT query as shown at http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/loading-data-using-ontorefine.html#rdfize-data-using-sparql. (BTW, have you tried the new mapping UI? Most people will find it easier to use).

You can also insert the data directly to GraphDB using [internal federation](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/internal-federation.html). Use the Ontorefine "RDF" button to find the Ontorefine virtual endpoint `xxxx` then make a query like this:

```
insert {
  <same pattern as CONSTRUCT>
} where {
  service <ontorefine:xxxx> {
    <same pattern as for Ontorefine>
  }
}
```

Comment: Now there are 2 ways: SPARQL query or visual RDF mapping. See the answer by Pavel